# Jenkins postScript build to run bouth on Slave and afterards on master

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins running and building on a node/slave and archive the artifacts(Post build Action) back to master.

All good, but I need to run a script on the master afterwards - I need to copy the artifact to a IIS site on the master. PostBuildScript plugin only seams to run on the slave.

Should I create a new job to be run afterwards, and if so can I use the Environ variables... or how would you do it?

Thanks in advance

Regards
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new Job running on the server.